# Does Twin Shadows seek stealthed champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new Season 3 item [Twin Shadows](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twin_Shadows) has the following active:

```
Unique Active: Hunt - Summons 2 invulnerable ghosts for 6 seconds to seek the 
two nearest enemy champions. If they touch an enemy champion, they slow his 
movement speed by 40% and reveal him for 2.5 seconds. 120 second cooldown.
```

I just tried it in a game, and it revealed a Garen who was hiding in some brush, previously out of my vision. The active states that it seeks the two nearest enemy champions, revealing them on contact. Does this include stealthed champions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some quick testing, it would appear as though Twin Shadows will not seek out stealthed champions. A friend and I tested this out on Teemo (apologies for the low quality):

I also tested it before on Twitch, though I didn't record the evidence; Twin Shadows did not reveal that time either. This leads me to believe that **Twin Shadows will not seek stealthed champions**.

Comment: Thanks for actually making a video from it, nice job. +1

Comment: It's surprising, though. I would have thought that the main point of this item was to be a stealth revealer

Comment: See also: [Rift Myths video about it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rFJh9xpXhjY#t=45s)

Answer (score 1):

Stealth champions are **not** revealed.